# Android Camera2 - Draw circle focus area

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to develop a custom application that uses Camera 2 API and I would like to add the feature "tap to focus". In other words, when I tap on the screen to focus, it shows a circle of the focus area.

How can I draw the circle focus area?

I followed the Google [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) example.

Thank you.

Comment: did you get it to work? I have the same question! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be enough is draw circle of tap area, not focus area? In this case You can save X and Y pos of tap and use it as center of circle. And You can use any tutorial for drawing over camera preview, like [that](http://seshadripera.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-draw-overlay-on-surfaceview-used.html).